# Cannot install gem file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been on this for a few hrs already googled everything. Tried tons of answers, im using ruby x64 and devkit x64 (originaly isntalled the incorect one x32 but i just deleted it and installed the correct one x64)
Cant install json or (my actual target) ruby-debug-ide -v 0.4.32
gem version = 2.4.7
ruby version =ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gem install json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20171013-12212-1y42085.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
c:/ruby24-x64/programing/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/json-2.1.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: It looks like it's missing the GMP library, or whatever provides the library `gmp`. Is there any reason you need to use the gem when there's a built-in [JSON library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a cloud9 editor, and per this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning
It will save you quite a bit of pain setting up your rails environment.